# Problema para mostrar sólo los atributos que necesito de una clase en una WebApi

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, webapi

Estoy realizando un proyecto WebApi en C# en Visual Studio Community 2017. Mi problema es que realizo el "get" para traer los datos de una clase mediante una consulta a una base de datos almacenada en SQL 2008 (select login, clave from usuario) y me muestra TODOS los atributos de la clase (login y clave bien, nombre, apellido, fecha de nac, sexo, etc todos en cero o nulos); yo sólo quiero mostrar los atributos que necesito (login y clave). Espero haber sido claro y que puedan ayudarme. Saludos. Y desde ya muchas gracias.

El código que pude realizar es éste:

CLASE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UserLogin.Models
{
    public partial class User
    {
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Apellido { get; set; }
        public string FechaNac { get; set; }
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Login { get; set; }
        public string Clave { get; set; }
    }
}
```

INTERFAZ

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UserLogin.Models;

namespace UserLogin.DataProvider
{
    public interface IUserDataProvider
    {   
        Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsers();

        Task<User> GetUser(string UserID);

        Task AddUser(User user);

        Task UpdateUser(User user);

        Task DeleteUser(string UserID);
    }
}
```

CAPA DE ACCESO A DATOS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UserLogin.Models;
using Dapper;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace UserLogin.DataProvider
{
    public class UserDataProvider : IUserDataProvider
    {
        private readonly string connectionstring = "Conexion";

        //Todos los usuarios
        public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsers()
        {
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
                return await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<User>(
                    "select login, clave from usuarios");
            }
        }
     }
```

CONTROLADOR

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UserLogin.DataProvider;
using UserLogin.Models;

namespace UserLogin.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]

    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUserDataProvider userDataProvider;

        public UserController(IUserDataProvider userDataProvider)
        {
            this.userDataProvider = userDataProvider;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> Get()
        {
            return await this.userDataProvider.GetUsers();
        }
      }
 }
```

Comment: Pero ¿Qué has probado?¿Qué problemas has encontrado? completa el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como estructurar una pregunta, si tu pregunta es de calidad, seguro que encuentras una respuesta de calidad también, y más importante, a otros les podrá servir esta duda que tienes ahora mismo. Para más info mira también [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo Responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: El problema es el que he comentado, en el navegador me muestra todos los atributos de la clase, los que necesito y los que no. Los que necesito me los muestra correctamente y los que no necesito están en cero o nulos. Lo que necesito es que en el navegador aparezcan sólo los atributos de la clase que pido en el select de la consulta a la base de datos.

Comment: Puedes mostrar tu código, para tratar de solucionar el problema un poco más rápido?

Comment: Bien, me va a llevar unos minutos. Te comento lo que he logrado hacer hasta ahora. He podido crear un clase y crear la interfaz donde indico los métodos. Luego implemento los métodos en una capa de acceso a datos. Por último conecto las funcionalidades con un controlador donde defino las rutas.

Comment: Y porqué no creas un modelo específico para esa vista? uno que solo contenga los campos/propiedades que quieres mostrar.

Comment: Lo he pensado e implementado. Pero no me sirve porque luego voy a tener que utilizar el resto de las propiedades en el futuro. Habrá algún problema en implementar lo que propones además de la repetición de código??. Además he probado realizar otro modelo pequeño con las propiedades que debo mostrar y usar herencia para heredar sus propiedades en el modelo que contiene el resto de las propiedades, pero si luego necesito mostrar otras propiedades diferentes a la del modelo pequeño tampoco me sirve. Estoy buscando alguna otra solución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que necesitas se llama DTO (Data Transfer Object), son clases que tienen únicamente lo que requieres, y no toda la estructura de la tabla.

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Clave { get; set; }
}
```

Y tendrías que modificar tu método:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UserDTO>> GetUsers()
{
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring)) {
        await sqlConnection.OpenAsync();
        var dbResult = await sqlConnection.QueryAsync<User>(
            "select login, clave from usuarios");
        return  dbResult.Select(user => new UserDTO { 
                Login = item.Login, 
                Clave = item.Clave
        });
    }
}
```

De esta forma solo expones en tu API lo que realmente necesitas.

Comment: Bien Luis. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo. Una última consulta... Éste método ralentiza la consulta cuando se trata de una cantidad considerable de datos??. O va a ser imperceptible si es que hay alguna ralentización??.

Comment: La consulta es exactamente la misma, simplemente hay una conversion de User -> UserDTO y se hace en memoria, asi que debería ser imperceptible. Por cierto, modifiqué el método, es mas corto usando linq.

Comment: Si, usé el método que expusiste con linq, funciona perfecto. Ahora tuve problemas cuando quiero mostrar información que está en otra clase. Por ejemplo quiero mostrar la localidad de donde es el usuario, esa localidad está en otra clase Localidad, yo sólo tengo el IDLocalidad en la tabla Usuario. Alguna idea de cómo puedo solucionar éste problema??. Yo lo que hago es usar el Multi Mapping de Dapper, pero no me está funcionando.